# How to add line in scene in three.js?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, three.js

I try to add a line in three.js. But when call the addline function in my code it doesn't appear in the scene. I try to use MVC design pattern. I don't know where i made mistake. Thanks for your help.
My code is below:

```
function View(viewArea) {
    var viewport = document.getElementById(viewArea);
    var viewportHeight = document.getElementById(viewArea).offsetHeight;
    var viewportWidth = document.getElementById(viewArea).offsetWidth;

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( viewportWidth, viewportHeight );
    viewport.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, viewportWidth / viewportHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    camera.position.set(100,70,3000);
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
    light.position.set(100,100,100);
    scene.add(light);

    this.scene = scene;
    this.camera = camera;
    this.light = light;
    this.renderer = renderer;
}

View.prototype.addLine = function (geometry) {
    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x000000 });
    var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
    this.scene.add( line );
};

View.prototype.render = function () {
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
};

function Controller(viewArea) {
    var view = new View(viewArea);

    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0) );
    for(var i=0;i<100;i+=10){
        geometry.vertices.push(
            new THREE.Vector3(i,i+10,i+20)
        );
        view.addLine(geometry);
    }
    view.render();
}
```

My HTML code is:

```
<body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" id="leftMenu">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                    <div class="row" id="viewport">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" id="informationMenu">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" id="rightMenu">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
             var controller = new Controller('viewport');
        });   
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: any errors in dev console?

Comment: No. There is no error

Comment: can you put console.log(geometry);  inside addline() to see if geometry has values..

Comment: Yes i tried to this. And geometry has values

Comment: take this line out why do you need that ...  geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0) ); or start the loop from var i=1 if you want to keep that line. as "i" will be 0 when loop will first execute.

Comment: No, it didn't work. Actually geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0) ); that doesn't belong my code. Just i try maybe it is working.

Comment: maybe your camera is to far away to see the line. have you tried to add bigger sized objects?

Comment: Thanks for your helping. I found my mistake. **var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x000000 });** color writing is wrong. And my camera is far away. Sorry i wasted your time.

Comment: @ŞeymaYaman glad you solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here:

- your line is black on a black background
- your camera is too far away and your line is being culled

Change these two lines of code:

This lets your camera see far enough to show your line.

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, viewportWidth / viewportHeight, 0.1, 5000 );
```

This just makes your line pink

```
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff00ff });
```

That should do the trick, I hope that helps.

As an aside: I would add the line geometry to your scene only once. Try moving the `view.addLine(geometry)` outside of the loop.

```
function Controller(viewArea) {
    var view = new View(viewArea);

    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0) );
    for(var i=0;i<100;i+=10){
        geometry.vertices.push(
            new THREE.Vector3(i,i+10,i+20)
        );
    }

    view.addLine(geometry);
    view.render();
}
```

Here's a working pen:
http://codepen.io/BBlanchard/pen/RKdNoO

Answer (score 0):

**Try some thing like that** its basic example you can get the idea.

```js
 var renderer, scene, camera, controls;
 var geometry, material, line, vertices;
 init();

 function init() {
   document.body.style.cssText = 'margin: 0; overflow: hidden;';
   renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
     alpha: 1,
     antialias: true,
     clearColor: 0xffffff
   });
   renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
   document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

   scene = new THREE.Scene();
   camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
   camera.position.set(5, 5, 5);
   controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

   material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
     color: 0x0077ff
   });
   geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
   geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

   line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material)

   scene.add(line);
   addLine(); // add line
 }

 function addLine() {
   vertices = geometry.vertices;
  for(var i=0;i<100;i+=10){
     vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(i,i+10,i+20));
     }
   geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
   geometry.vertices = vertices;
   scene.remove(line);
   line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material)
   scene.add(line);
   renderer.render(scene, camera);
 }
```

```html
<script src=http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/build/three.min.js></script>
<script src=http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I get it this idea